# Laravel: Mail markup for single newline?

Tags: php, laravel-5, markup

When I hit return in the `email.blade.php` file it does not create a new line. 
However, according to the [markdown rules](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet#lines) it should.

Thats my blade file:

```
@component('mail::message')
# Introduction

First line
Second line

third line...
@endcomponent
```

and that is how it looks in my browser:

[image]

Why is there no line break before `Second line`?

Comment: Markdown comes in different flavors. I don't know the exact rules that apply here, but have you tried to end the line you want to break with _two_ spaces? This is sometimes the rule for line breaks.

Comment: @HielkeWalinga thank you, 2 spaces worked.. What a nice ******** rule.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Can you show the generated HTML?

I'm guessing it's because you're using soft line breaks instead of hard line breaks.
More info here - [soft](https://github.github.com/gfm/#soft-line-breaks) vs [hard](https://github.github.com/gfm/#hard-line-breaks) line breaks.

Comment: Thats correct. In short, I have to use 2 white spaces before the return.